# jsp page not selecting dropdown by default

Tags: jsp

My dropdown doesnt select the value by default in jsp page and it is not printing the values in console:

```
<select id="dropdown">
<c:forEach var="item" items="${requestForm.Approve}">
<c:set var = "itemId" value = '${item.id}: ${item.display}'/> 
<option value="<c:out value='${item.id}: ${item.display}' />"
<c:if test="${itemId == requestForm.Approve}"> selected </c:if>  > 
<% out.println("value of item id is         "+pageContext.findAttribute("itemId")); %></option></c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: The `out` PrintWriter object is bound to the response, not the console.  View source in your browser and check out the generated html.

Comment: I checked the generated html it is displaying all the dropdown values and it is not showing anyone selected.I am getting values as below:<option value="204:Aena.gero">204:Aena, gero</option>
<option value="537:Dro, Beth">537:Dro, Beth</option>

Comment: In that case, show the value you're looking for somewhere on the page: `${requestForm.Approve}`.  It appears that no itemId is equal to this value, whatever it is.